# Local password for remote connections

Tags: windows-10, encryption, vnc

By default you log in to your PC and then connect a remote like Team Viewer or VNC.
But problem with VNC is that you have a unencrypted login.
So I thought I would have a last stop at my PC to force a extra login for all remote controllers.

I'm on a Windows 10 PC, but I'm usually using Windows 8.1 guide. The old ways are just under the surface.

I've tried Google abit but only seen how to remove password upon connections which is the opposite of what I want.

Some guidance here and maybe a reference to more information about encryption would be appreciated.
Thanks, have a nice day at your PC.

Comment: How about tunnelling VNC over SSH for encryption. http://crl.ucsd.edu/handbook/vnc/

Comment: I'm familiar with ssh, handling server for games and website. Will I be able to see my desktop? (If I configure it correctly)

Comment: Yes, Google search for tunnelling VNC over SSH.  You encrypt the VNC data through SSH so VNC works as normal after it is all setup.